# Bookshelf change column data type

Tags: javascript, mysql, bookshelf.js

I`m using bookshelf.js and I want to change the data type column, this is the example I want to do.

```
select * from table where date(datetime_col) = '2017-03-14'
```

the datatime_col is DATETIME and I want to convert to date to execute the query.

this is how I'm trying to do in bookshelf

```
var Model =  new model().query(function (qb) {
        qb.where('date(datetime_col)', '=' , date);
    }).fetchAll()
```

this is the error when I´m trying to execute the code above

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'date(datetime_col)' in 'where clause'
```

This is a full example how can you use knex.raw and bookshelf for query thanks for answer.

Using between two dates with date time column

```
var Model =  new model().query(function (qb) {
        qb.whereBetween( Bookshelf.knex.raw("DATE(colum_datetime)"), [date_var1, date_var2]);
    }).fetchAll( { withRelated: ['table1', 'table2', {'table3':function (qb) {
        qb.orderBy('date_column', 'desc')
    }},'table4']  });
```

Using where

```
var Model =  new model().query("where", Bookshelf.knex.raw("DATE(colum_datetime)"), "=", date_var).fetchAll( { withRelated: ['table1', 'teble2', {'table3':function (qb) {
    qb.orderBy('date_column', 'desc')
}},'table4']  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that "bookshelf.js" or the underlying "knex" expect to get an attribute name of your model (like `datetime_col`), and not a sql-fragment like `date(datetime_col)`.

According to [this source](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/80), you need to pass a part with the function as "raw" sql. 
The proposed solution is to write it like this:

```
model.query("where", Bookshelf.knex.raw("DATE(field) = ?"), "2017-03-04"))
```